# Assertion null in running group of tests

Tags: java, exception, mockito, testng

Am newbie to Unit testing. Am using TestNG and Mockito for unit test. I have 8 test cases when running the test cases one by one it's working fine. After that i have added all those methods in one class. After running the test class i got Assertion null exception. Am not able to find the root cause. Here is my code.

```
public class TestLoginController {

@Mock
DBResourseLoader dbResourceLoader;

@Mock
MessageLoader messageLoader;

@Mock
Logger logger;

@Mock
Properties properties;

@Mock
Properties databaseProperties;

@Mock
DBConnector connector;

@Mock
Connection connection;

@Mock
PropertyConfigurator propertyConfigurator;

@InjectMocks
LoginBean loginBean;

@Mock
CommonDAO commonDAO;

@Mock 
PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

@Mock
ResultSet resultSet;




@BeforeClass
public void setup() {
    try {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(messageLoader.getMessageStatement("")).thenReturn("");
        when(dbResourceLoader.getJdbcDatasource()).thenReturn(properties);
        when(dbResourceLoader.getLogger()).thenReturn(databaseProperties);
        when(dbResourceLoader.getLogger(Logger.class)).thenReturn(logger);

        when(connector.getConnection(true)).thenReturn(connection);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@BeforeMethod
public void setBeforeValues() {


}

@Test
public void negTestCheckIsReportCreatedByCustomerReportFlagByNo() {
    try {
        when(commonDAO.getLoginControllerValue("LOGIN_CONTROLLER")).thenReturn("NO");
        reset(commonDAO);
        assertNotEquals(false, loginBean.checkIsReportCreatedByCustomer("1234@1234.com"));
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Test
public void posTestCheckIsReportCreatedByCustomerReportFlagByNo() {
    try {

        when(commonDAO.getLoginControllerValue("LOGIN_CONTROLLER")).thenReturn("NO");
        assertEquals(true, loginBean.checkIsReportCreatedByCustomer("1234@1234.com"));

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Test
public void negTestCheckIsReportCreatedByCustomerByReportFlagYes() {
    try {
        when(commonDAO.getLoginControllerValue("LOGIN_CONTROLLER")).thenReturn("YES");
        when(commonDAO.getCustomerReportCreationValue("1234@gmail.com")).thenReturn(false);
        assertNotEquals(true, loginBean.checkIsReportCreatedByCustomer("1234@1234.com"));
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Test
public void posTestCheckIsReportCreatedByCustomerByReportFlagYes() {
    try {
        when(commonDAO.getLoginControllerValue("LOGIN_CONTROLLER")).thenReturn("YES");
        when(commonDAO.getCustomerReportCreationValue("1234@1234.com")).thenReturn(true);
        assertEquals(true, loginBean.checkIsReportCreatedByCustomer("1234@1234.com"));
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Test
public void negTestCheckLoginAlertReportFlagByNo() {
    try {
        when(commonDAO.getLoginControllerValue("LOGIN_CONTROLLER")).thenReturn("NO");
        assertNotEquals(false, loginBean.checkIsReportCreatedByCustomer("1234@1234.com"));
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Test
public void posTestLoginAlertCustomerReportFlagByNo() {
    try {
                    when(commonDAO.getLoginControllerValue("LOGIN_CONTROLLER")).thenReturn("NO");
        assertEquals(true, loginBean.checkIsReportCreatedByCustomer("1234@1234.com"));

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Test
public void negTestLoginAlertByReportFlagYes() {
    try {
        when(commonDAO.getLoginControllerValue("LOGIN_CONTROLLER")).thenReturn("YES");
        when(commonDAO.getCustomerReportCreationValue("1234@gmail.com")).thenReturn(false);
        assertNotEquals(true, loginBean.checkIsReportCreatedByCustomer("1234@1234.com"));
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Test
public void posTestCheckLoginAlertByReportFlagYes() {
    try {
        when(commonDAO.getLoginControllerValue("LOGIN_CONTROLLER")).thenReturn("YES");
        when(commonDAO.getCustomerReportCreationValue("1234@1234.com")).thenReturn(true);
        assertEquals(true, loginBean.checkIsReportCreatedByCustomer("1234@1234.com"));
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

And the exception is

```
FAILED: negTestCheckLoginAlertReportFlagByNo
java.lang.AssertionError: null
at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
at org.testng.Assert.assertNotEquals(Assert.java:897)
at org.testng.Assert.assertNotEquals(Assert.java:902)
at 
com.test.login.controller.TestLoginController.
negTestCheckLoginAlertReportFlagByNo(TestLoginController.java:146)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.
invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.
invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the complete stack trace and identify the statement in your code that throws the exception.

Comment: Which testCase?

Comment: I have updated the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

So the assertion that fails is in `negTestCheckLoginAlertReportFlagByNo`.  All the `null` is telling you is that you didn't provide a custom message.

The issue is that the return from

```
loginBean.checkIsReportCreatedByCustomer("1234@1234.com")
```

was `false`.

As to why that is we cannot possibly help.  It is now up to you to determine if the test is faulty or the code being tested is behaving incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

If the test `negTestCheckLoginAlertReportFlagByNo` really succeeds on its own, then it could be some other tests influence its outcome, and the test execution order should be controlled, using either priority or [dependency](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods) mechanism of TestNG.

---

As a side note, I would consider the following expression hard to read, because it can be easily misinterpreted:

```
assertNotEquals(false, loginBean.checkIsReportCreatedByCustomer("1234@1234.com"));
```

I would suggest using methods `assertTrue`, `assertFalse` in this case, as they are a little more obvious.

So, either:

```
assertFalse(loginBean.checkIsReportCreatedByCustomer("1234@1234.com"));
```

if the check should return `false`, or:

```
assertTrue(loginBean.checkIsReportCreatedByCustomer("1234@1234.com"));
```

if it should return `true`.